# Backbone.js bind this to $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using backbonejs and inside a method I have:

```
$.each(response.error, function(index, item) {
    this.$el.find('.error').show();
});
```

However, because it's in `$.each`, `this.$el` is undefined.

I have `_.bindAll(this, 'methodName')` which will work outside of the each.  So, now I need to bind it within?

Any help woudl be great!  Thank you

Comment: Ack. I just re-read the question, this isn't a dupe of the one I posted. Disregard that. Sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using Backbone so you have Underscore and that means that you have [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

> **each** `_.each(list, iterator, [context])`
>
> Iterates over a **list** of elements, yielding each in turn to an **iterator** function. The **iterator** is bound to the **context** object, if one is passed.

So you could do this:

```
_.each(response.error, function(item, index) {
    this.$el.find('.error').show();
}, this);
```

Or you could use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
$.each(response.error, _.bind(function(index, item) {
    this.$el.find('.error').show();
}, this));
```

Or, since you're finding the same thing over and over again, precompute and stop caring about `this`:

```
var $error = this.$el.find('.error');
$.each(response.error, function(index, item) {
    $error.show();
});
```

Here's a quick demo of the two Underscore approaches: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dNgEa/

Answer (score 2):

Set a local variable before looping:

```
var self = this;
$.each(response.error, function(index, item) {
    self.$el.find('.error').show();
});
```