# Looping through elements with the same class in Backbone View with .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone and JQuery and would like to create a Backbone View to [create equal height columns as described in method 2 of this link](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/). The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div  id="leftcolumn" class="set_equal_height"> … Lots Of Content … </div>
 <div id="middlecolumn" class="set_equal_height"> … Lots Of Content … </div>
 <div  id="rightcolumn" class="set_equal_height"> … Lots Of Content … </div>
</div>
```

I put together the following Backbone View but it's not working presumably because the loop using .each is not working (the page loads with no errors, but the height of the columns is not modified by the javascript):

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
], function($, _, Backbone) {
  var SetEqualHeight = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      var tallestcolumn = 0;
      console.log(this.$el.height());
      console.log(this.$el.attr("id"));
      this.$el.each(function() {
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        console.log(currentHeight);
        if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
            tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
        }
      });
    this.$el.height(tallestcolumn);
    },
  });
  return SetEqualHeight;
});
```

I'm defining the "el" argument in a separate Wire specification as follows: { el: 'div.set_equal_height' }, and it is passing correctly since the "console.log(this.$el.height())" and console.log(this.$el.attr("id")) in the code above print out correctly. However the console.log inside the ".each" statement doesn't print out, showing that there is a problem with the ".each". I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354100/backbone-js-bind-this-to-each) and tried out the Underscore "_.each" method but could not figure out how to iterate through elements with a given class (i.e. div.set_equal_height) instead of a given array. Could anyone enlighten me about making .each work in the above Backbone View? Please!!!

Just for reference, the following function works by itself (I'm looking to incorporate it as a Backbone view or view helper):

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
 var tallestcolumn = 0;
 columns.each(function() {
  currentHeight = $(this).height();
  if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
   tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
  }
 });
 columns.height(tallestcolumn);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 setEqualHeight($("div.set_equal_height"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are instantiating your view with something like this?

```
new SetEqualHeight({el: '.container')
```

If so, that means that `$el` will be set to the container div inside your view.  `$(anything).each` will iterate though all members of "`anything`" ... but in your case there is only one member (`'.container'`).

The solution is to change this line:

```
this.$el.each(function() {
```

to:

```
this.$el.find('.set_equal_height').each(function() {
```

or better yet (more Backbone-y):

```
this.$('.set_equal_height').each(function() {
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As a side note, this isn't really what views were designed for; this seems more like a helper/utility function, or better yet a jQuery plug-in.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the help machineghost. Just to clarify, I had instantiated SetEqualHeight with { el: 'div.set_equal_height' } (there are 3 div elements with that class, through which I was hoping to iterate with the ".each". Much like the sample function that I just included at the bottom of my question. I tried out using {el: 'container'} and the rest of your suggestion but it didn't make a difference (the .each statement is still not working). Regarding your comment about using a jQuery plugin instead of a backbone View, Could you orient me a bit about this? I'm new to backbone/Wire.js.

Comment: NP :-) So Backbone views are designed to have just one element, which is why your original code didn't work.  This is also why I recommended against using a view.  I'd recommend instead just making a helper function, or if you feel like learning something new you could learn how to make a jQuery plug-in (there are lots of tutorials, it's not hard), and then you could do $('.set_equal_height').setEqualHeight() ... if you called your plug-in setEqualHeight that is.

Comment: As for getting the each to work, I'd check two things: 1) in your code, check what `this.$el` actually is; if you are using Firefox/Firebug or Chrome with the developer tools turned on, you can do `console.log(this.$el)` to see.  If it is what you expect (your three divs), then 2) check how often your each is running (again, probably using a console.log inside of it) ... if that doesn't match the number of elements you see in `this.$el` something is *seriously* wrong.

Comment: Thanks machineghost. I tried but was not able to make the .each work as a helper function inside the backbone.view... I decided to go for the following to avoid using the .each statement:      this.$el.find('.set_equal_height').height(Math.max(
        ($('#left_wrapper').height()),
        ($('#middle_wrapper').height()),
        ($('#right_wrapper').height())
      ));

Comment: It's strange that you couldn't get each to work, but I'm glad to hear you at least got some equivalent code that did.